# call another function in same file helper codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

halo everyone. now im doing task using CI (CodeIgniter) framework. i made a function in helper file. the question is. do we can call another function in same helper file. i give example

file "common_helper.php"

```
function calculation($param)
{
    $result = $this->discount($param);
    return $result;
}

function discount($param)
{
    $total = $param * 10%;
    return $total;
}
```

so in function "calculation" want to call function "discount".. but i cant use "$this->discount($param)". is there another way for this?

the second is

i got error when i create this function in helper

```
function flatten_multi_array_and_get_unique($multi)
{
    $objTmp = (object) array('aFlat' => array());
    array_walk_recursive($multi, create_function('&$v, $k, &$t', '$t->aFlat[] = $v;'), $objTmp);

    $res = array_unique($objTmp->aFlat);

    return $res;
}
```

the error warning is "Function create_function() is deprecated"  what should i do?

Comment: directly call discount() because $this is used in reference of a class and here is no class only functions

Comment: ahh. thank you!!! it works

Answer (score 0):

For the second part you can use an [**anonymous function**](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) aka. closure function

```
function flatten_multi_array_and_get_unique($multi)
{
    $objTmp = (object) array('aFlat' => array());
    array_walk_recursive($multi, function(&$v, $k, &$t){ $t->aFlat[] = $v; }, $objTmp);

    $res = array_unique($objTmp->aFlat);

    return $res;
}
```

Find interesting? [Read more](https://www.elated.com/articles/php-anonymous-functions/)